# Set UIScrollView delegate to it's own custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I created a custom component from UIScrollView.

I create a custom UIScrollview class and add it to my scroll view.

And in the custom class in "- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect" I design my scroll view the way I wanted. and its all working fine.

My Question is how to add my scrollview as the delegate of the Custom class.

I did this inside my custom class -

```
self.delegate = self;
```

and the delegate get set and I have access to the UIScroll view delegate methods (like - - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView).

My problem is once I set my delegate like 'self.delegate = self;' compiler gives me a warning like below

[image]

Please can anyone help me to fix this warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your custom class as conforming to the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

Check out the [Apple docs on protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW3).

In your header file, you probably have something like

```
@interface OGOTimeSelector : UIScrollView
```

To declare that your class conforms to the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, this would become:

```
@interface OGOTimeSelector : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Yep Its working now. Thank you for the quick answer.